# how to implement real-time multiplayer google play game service c++ into cocos2d-x

Tags: android, c++, cocos2d-x, google-play-games

I am currently developing a real-time multiplayer application , I managed to implement (submitScore, unlockAchievement, incrementAchievement ...) but i couldn't  implement the phase of real-time multiplayer,
I followed [the official docs](https://developers.google.com/games/services/cpp/realtimeMultiplayer), but i could not even to create a multiplayer room

```
jni/../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp:180:16: error: no matching function for call to 'gpg::RealTimeMultiplayerManager::ShowWaitingRoomUI(gpg::RealTimeRoom&, const int32_t&, HelloWorld::QuickMatch()::<lambda(const gpg::RealTimeMultiplayerManager::RealTimeRoomResponse&)>::<lambda(const gpg::RealTimeMultiplayerManager::RealTimeRoomResponse&)>)'
               });
```

Someone can help me to implement this part

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed us the code snippet of what you tried instead of just a compile error.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really an solution, but it seems your compiler is not finding the gpg libraries. Check your .mk files to see if the proper library files are included.